# How can a string be inserted as code at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose I have this method:

```
1. public int sum(int a, int b){
2.     int x = 0;
3. 
4.     return x;
5. }
```

Is it possible to get a string `x = a + b;` and place in line 3 (during runtime), so that after this string is inserted, the code now does the sum of `a` and `b`?

I wanna write some code in a text input field, so when I press a button, all that code (that is a string) should be able to go inside some part of some existing code. The `sum` above is just an example but it can be anything.

Comment: do you really need to compile c#? you can do your own parser.if you just want to interpret the code for a "code minigame" for example.

Comment: I don't want to create a full parser, I intend to do slight modifications and convert the code to workable C#.

Comment: Look, your options are: a) Anu's answer b) Compile text code into a dynamically generated assembly (using CodeDom  as mentioned in the accepted answer in the linked question). There isn't really an in between option here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting string, you could pass a [Func<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.8) to the method as parameter. For example,

```
public int sum(int a, int b,Func<int,int,int> expression = null)
{
   int x = expression == null ? 0 : expression(a,b);
   return x;
}
```

Now, you could use the method as

```
var result1 = sum(1,2);  // When you do not want to add the numbers
var result2 = sum(1,2,(a,b)=>a+b); // when you want to add the numbers
```

Comment: My question was specific for a reason: the little string `x = a + b;` was just an example, but I wanna have a string that holds a lot of code that that performs lots of actions and put it into a `void` method at runtime. A lambda expression wouldn't fit because I'm expecting the user to write some code and I'll just insert it inside some existing code.